# joblib.Parallel running through spyder hanging on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, joblib

I'm running Python 3.5.1 on Windows Server 2013 at work. I have some embarrassingly parallel tasks that seem to work on Python 2.7 with basically the same code, but I am unable to figure out how to get it to run on Python 3.5.1.

I'm using Anaconda 2.4.1

The code looks like this... I've stripped it down to basically the minimum.

```
\
->main.py
\apackage\
->__init__.py
->amodule.py
```

Code for `main.py`

```
from tpackage import AClass

def go():
    x = AClass().AFunction()
    return x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = go()
    print(x)
```

Code for `__init__.py`

```
from .amodule import AClass

__all__ = ['AClass']
```

Code for `amodule.py`

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

class AClass(object):
    def AFunction(self):
        x = Parallel(n_jobs=2,verbose=100)(
            delayed(add1)(i) for i in range(10)
            )
        return x

def add1(x):   
    return x + 1
```

Does this have anything to do with the need for a `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement? I didn't think I would need this because the `Parallel` is protected inside a `def` statement already and *should* only run when the `__main__` module is called, which should only happen once.

I should add that if I change `n_jobs=1` in `amodule.py`, everything works fine.

**Update:**

So after further review, it appears that this probably something to do with spyder. I'm using spyder 2.3.8. When I have spyder execute this is a dedicated window, it works. But when it runs in the interactive IPython console, it fails. I can also run the program directly from the command line without problems.

**Update 2:**

After further review, this really has to do with IPython being in a different working directory than the *.py file. Get those lined up and this works.

Comment: Ok. I think I have this kind of working. There appears to be something funky going on with the directory structure. You have to be quite careful to ensure IPython is in the correct working directory... it often is not. I'm wondering if I should add some code to make sure that the directory is correct before starting the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) If this problem is caused by `runfile` setting the working directory, you can prevent that to happen by going to the menu entry

```
Run > Configuration per file
```

(or pressing `Ctrl+F6`) and selecting the option called *The current working directory*.

*Notes*:

1. The run configuration is saved for each file and Spyder remembers it after restarts.
2. The answer has been updated for Spyder **3.2** and above.