# Multiprocessing in Python using Pool

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-processing, spyder, pool

I want to parallelize a function on a dataframe using Python. I saw tutorials and I found some code.I have adjusted it to my needs. When I execute the map function the program freezes. The code seems to be solid. I wonder what the problem is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool

attributes1 = pd.read_csv('attributes1.csv')


def replace_data(data):
    for i in range(0, len(data.index)):
        temp = data.iloc[i, 1]
        temp = temp.replace('in.', 'inch')
        data.iloc[i, 1] = temp
    return data

num_partitions = 10 #number of partitions to split dataframe
num_cores = cpu_count() #number of cores on your machine

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

df1 = parallelize_dataframe(attributes1, replace_data)
```

Comment: What happens if you set `num_cores = 1`?

Comment: It still freezes!

Comment: what if you replace `pool.map` with just `map`?

Comment: It is working but it doesn't seem to run on parallel.

Comment: That was just to verify that it was running single-threadedly.. I just noticed that your last line isn't inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`, which will probably cause `multiprocessing` to run that line when starting a new process.

Comment: Still freezes. I found this. On Windows many types from multiprocessing need to be picklable so that child processes can use them. However, one should generally avoid sending shared objects to other processes using pipes or queues. Instead you should arrange the program so that a process which needs access to a shared resource created elsewhere can inherit it from an ancestor process. Does it relate to my problem?

Comment: There are no "shared" resources in multiprocessing, both arguments and results need to be packaged and shipped to each participating process. You wouldn't want shared-through-process-inheritance anyways, since that would linearize your program through the GIL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I found out that not even the basic parallel example won't be executed. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool I don't know what is going on. I have a windows 10 PC and anaconda installation and I run my code on the Spyder IDE

Comment: I don't know anything about Spyder, but maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821877/joblib-parallel-running-through-spyder-hanging-on-windows

Comment: Thank you again very much for your time. I appreciate it. I found the solution and it is weird!! I created another .py file in which I saved my replace_data function. Then from my main .py file I imported the function. I added also the line if __name__ == "__main__": as you said. Now the program runs smoothly. This is a problem for windows users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem for Windows users only. Firstly I created another .py file lets name it helpy.py where I have my replace_data function

```
def replace_data(data):
    for i in range(0, len(data.index)):
        temp = data.iloc[i, 1]
        temp = temp.replace('in.', 'inch')
        data.iloc[i, 1] = temp
    return data
```

Then I imported my function into my main .py file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool
from helpy import replace_data

attributes1 = pd.read_csv('attributes1.csv')


num_partitions = 10 #number of partitions to split dataframe
num_cores = cpu_count() #number of cores on your machine

    def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
        df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
        pool = Pool(num_cores)
        df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return df

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        df1 = parallelize_dataframe(attributes1, replace_data)
```

I also added the `if __name__ == '__main__':` Now the program runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using windows, for fixing it you need [`freeze_support`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.freeze_support):

```
from multiprocessing cpu_count, Pool, freeze_support

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    df1 = parallelize_dataframe(attributes1, replace_data)
```

Comment: Omitting `freeze_support` (when it's required, i.e. when using py2exe, PyInstaller, cx_Freeze) will raise `RuntimeError`, not freeze the program.