# Not printing output of function in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to use multiprocessing for my code, and I tried this example from here: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print('Worker:', num)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

However, when I run the code, it does not print anything. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

I am using Python 3 and Spider.

### Edit 1

Using sys.stdout.flush() does not help. I tried to add it to the worker function:

```
def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print('Worker:', num)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return
```

### Edit 2

Similar to this question [joblib.Parallel running through spyder hanging on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821877/joblib-parallel-running-through-spyder-hanging-on-windows), but even when I tried the suggested solution, it did not work:

[image]

### Edit 3

Indeed, by not using Spyder it worked:

[image]

Comment: What if you flush the buffer `sys.stdout.flush()`?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Thanks for your comment. I tried it. It did not change the output.

Comment: Could this be related to this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821877/joblib-parallel-running-through-spyder-hanging-on-windows

Comment: @po.pe I tried the suggested answer, but no change :/

Comment: Good thinking @po.pe I'd run the script outside Spyder. I have had my share of Spyder-caused issues.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Okay, thanks! I tried it, and indeed it seems to be a spyder problem (see EDIT 3). What IDE do you use?

Comment: Since I had very similar issues years back I switched to PyCharm. The latter features scientific mode that likely makes you appreciate Spyder. There's some learning curve (PyCharm is a more advanded IDE), but it's totally worth it.